# Неправильно читается ID из базы

Tags: sql

Всем привет, скажите у меня есть база где есть ID, я использую этот SQL запрос, чтобы считывать данные "без дырок", вот мой SQL запрос

```
SELECT URL FROM t_links ORDER BY ID
```

Но у меня программа берет ID самый последний, а не самый первый. Как исправить?

Comment: А что делает программа?
Возможно, она в цикле присваивает переменной значение из запроса. Последнее присвоенное значение вы и видите. :-)

Comment: Программа должна считывать СУЩЕСТВУЮЩИЕ ID из базы, после выбирать URL, и компонент WebBrowser должен его показать. Короче говоря механизм "Авто-Сёрфинга". Беда в том что я не могу сформулировать вопрос... Искал человека который знает SQL и C# в скайпе... не нашёл, а тут надо рассказать, а это не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT URL FROM t_links ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Всё работает на +100500! Но можно ещё вопрос, скажите как можно сделать так чтобы при срабатывании например таймера(ну это я сам уже сделаю) тот ID который был(например ID =1), увеличивался на 1(т.е стал ID = 2)?

Comment: Например так:

    UPDATE t_links SET ID = ID + 1 WHERE ID = ТутВашID

Comment: Блин((( А если я ID не могу указать...Вы думаю знаете как работают авто-сёрфинги... они ищут **существующие** ID, и просто в порядке возрастание просматриваются...

Answer (score 1):

А так?

```
SELECT URL FROM t_links ORDER BY ID limit 1
```